# Trapping and printing accesses to object members

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let us say that I have a model of a typical core with 32bit GPR's (denoted by `R` in the example below) which in turn are objects of type `Bitstring`, which provides methods to implement custom slicing methods.

```
class core:
    def __init__(self):
        self.R = [Bitstring(0x0, 32) for reg in range(32)]
        ...
        ...
```

I might have accesses to these registers which fall into two categories:

Cat a) --> single access to full or part of a register:

```
Eg:core.R[10] = 0x1000 OR core.R[11][0:3] = 0x8
```

Cat b): --> Multiple statements assigning different parts of the same register:

```
Eg:core.R[0][0:7] = core.R[10][28:31]
   core.R[0][8:15] = 0x10
```

Whenever a register gets accessed in either categories above, I would like to log a print with the format:

```
R r<num> <value> 
Eg:R r10 0xaabbccdd
```

Where `<num>` is the register number in the range `0, 31` and `<value>` is the value assigned to that register.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need this for quickly debugging your code, you could temporarily wrap your `Bitstring` objects in proxies that hook into the relevant behavior. A proxy could look like:

```
class Proxy(object):
    def __init__(self, proxied, outerindex):
        self.proxied = proxied
        self.outerindex = outerindex
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        logger.debug("Observing access of %r at %r:%r", (self.proxied, self.outerindex, index))
        return self.proxied[index]
    # __setitem__ similarly
```

At construction time, you need to wrap the `i`th `Bitstring` `b` in `proxy(b, i)` to access both indices from the logger. This assumes that you use no methods on `Bitstring`s other than these (or you have to add them to the proxy as well). The indirection has some costs and is kinda ugly, so if you want to keep this functionality, you might be better off by implementing accessor methods and only log in a subclass of `core`.

Comment: This is not for debugging per se, but to provide a consistent format for logging core states as the simulation of the core progresses. The problem is I need to print in the same format (i.e. R r<num> <value>) ONLY ONCE for CatA and CatB. Output should be R r10 0x00001000 for core.R[10] = 0x1000 and R r11 0x80000000 for core.R[11][0:3] = 0x8, R r0 0xXXXXXXXX (i.e. single print) for core.R[0][0:7] = core.R[10][28:31] and core.R[0][8:15] = 0x10. The challenge I am facing is that core.R[10][0:3] calls getitem on R and then getitem on Bitstring, so not sure where to add the logging.